# SGX Quote attestation with IAS

Tags: json, rest, ias, sgx

I was able to use run SGX in hardware mode and retrieve the SigRL successfully from IAS. But I'm struggling when trying to perform the Quote attestation using their REST API. I used the REST API interface description [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/3d/c8/IAS_1_0_API_spec_1_1_Final.pdf).
I connected successfully to the server with the HTTP POST request

```
https://test-as.sgx.trustedservices.intel.com:443/attestation//sgx/v1/report
```

But I always receive an error: 400 Bad request!?

On the client side I get msg3 as follows

```
ret = sgx_ra_proc_msg2(this->enclave->getContext(),
                               this->enclave->getID(),
                               sgx_ra_proc_msg2_trusted,
                               sgx_ra_get_msg3_trusted,
                               p_msg2,
                               size,
                               &p_msg3,
                               &msg3_size);
```

which returns `SGX_SUCCESS`.
Then I prepare the quote in the p_msg3 structure

```
std::string quoteStr = ConvertToString(p_msg3->quote);
quoteStr = EncodeToBase64(quoteStr);
```

and finally I put the quote in the JSON string which results in

```
{"isvEnclaveQuote": "MDIwMDAxMDBlMzBhMDAwMDA0MDA...RiMjUyYTgxOGE4NTIzMzQxZDY3"}
```

which is now sent as payload to the IAS.

Answer (score 1):

`400 Bad Request` is generally returned if there is something wrong with your Quote.

Please double check whether the **SPID** and **linkability** options you used to create the Quote match and the one you used to register with **IAS**.